# Observer for registration also fires login observer

Tags: event-observer

I have two observers, one for customer_register_success, and one for customer_login which work very well. The issue I'm having is when a customer registers, magento redirects to the login request, and subsequently fires the observer for that. Both are designed to do the same task in a slightly different way, where requests are sent to an external service via api calls, and as you know, api calls can be used up if not used carefully, so avoiding redundancy is critical. Is there a way to set some kind of persistence to avoid the second observer from being fired?

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing this, I thought about the possibility of setting a cookie value that can be checked on the second request.

```
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('key','value');
```

Will set the custom cookie value, then in the 2nd observer I added

```
if (Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('key') == 'value') 
{
   return $this;
}
```

Or if you want to get rid of the cookie value, use `Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->delete('key');` right above `return $this;`

[Mage_Core_Model_Cookie source code](http://freegento.com/doc/d7/d70/_cookie_8php-source.html)

Of course any other suggestions you can think of are definitely welcome.

Comment: using a session variable should work equally good

Comment: Yes I believe the model or singleton is `core/session` for that. 
Edit: Yep it is. See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340982/how-do-i-save-value-in-my-own-session-variable-in-magento